# How can i redirect alert button on chice using sweetAlert js?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I'm using sweetAlert this is working fine with single button but now i want to click button with choice but I'm not able to that, What is wrong?

Now my redirection is working on both buttons but i want to click only for single button. How can i do that?

What i tried:-

```js
function CallMessage() {
  swal({
    title: 'this is title',
    text: 'message',
    buttons: ["Finish Now", "Exit Anyway"]
  }).then(function() {
    window.location = 'login.aspx';
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="CallMessage();">Button</button>
```

Answer will be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise returned by `swal()` is resolved to the value of the clicked button. When using the array shorthand to set the `buttons` property, the first (cancel) button returns `null`, while the rest return `true`:

```js
function CallMessage() {
  swal({
    title: 'this is title',
    text: 'message',
    buttons: [ 'Finish Now', 'Exit Anyway' ]
  }).then(value => {
    console.log(value);

    if (value) {
      console.log('Redirecting!');
      // location.href = 'login.aspx';
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="CallMessage();">Button</button>
```

If you have more than two buttons, you can also set custom values for each one using an object instead of an array. See the [Advanced Examples](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples) section of the docs for more details.